# swipe back hides some navigation item in swift

Tags: ios, navigationitem

I have a problem regarding swipe back gestures in swift. After I push the new uicollectionviewcontroller when certain cell is pressed at the parent uicollectionviewcontroller, I swipe back to the parent viewcontroller. But only a few navigationitems appear on the navigation bar. However, when I go back by pressing the "back" button, all the navigation items appear. Here's my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
         setupNavBarButtons()}

func setupNavBarButtons(){
    let flexible = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil)
    flexible.isEnabled = false
    let logoImg = UIImage(named: "wee")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    let homeBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image:logoImg, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleHome))
    homeBarButtonItem.isEnabled = false
    let cameraImg = UIImage(named: "nav bar_circles")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    let cameraButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image:cameraImg, style: .plain, target: self, action: nil)

    cameraButtonItem.isEnabled = false
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [flexible, cameraButtonItem, flexible, cameraButtonItem, flexible, cameraButtonItem]
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [flexible, cameraButtonItem, flexible, cameraButtonItem, flexible, cameraButtonItem, flexible,  homeBarButtonItem]

    navigationItem.accessibilityElementsHidden = false

    navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = false
    navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false


}

func showAppDetailForApp(pht: UIImage){

    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let detailLauncher = ShowPhoto(collectionViewLayout: layout)
    detailLauncher.info = pht
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
    navigationController?.pushViewController(detailLauncher, animated: true)

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please Set below code line in your pushed view controller's viewDidLoad() method.

```
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false
```

Comment: Only the last items on rightItems and leftItems appear